# How to pass text in a textbox to JavaScript function?

Tags: javascript, html

Suppose I have the following HTML code, how can I pass the user's input to execute(str) JavaScript function as an argument?

```
<body>

<input name="textbox1" type="text" />
<input name="buttonExecute" onclick="execute(//send the user's input in textbox1 to this function//)" type="button" value="Execute" />

</body>
```

Comment: Thanks for all the answers. :)

Answer (score 36, accepted):

You could either access the element’s value by its name:

```
document.getElementsByName("textbox1"); // returns a list of elements with name="textbox1"
document.getElementsByName("textbox1")[0] // returns the first element in DOM with name="textbox1"
```

So:

```
<input name="buttonExecute" onclick="execute(document.getElementsByName('textbox1')[0].value)" type="button" value="Execute" />
```

Or you assign an ID to the element that then identifies it and you can access it with `getElementById`:

```
<input name="textbox1" id="textbox1" type="text" />
<input name="buttonExecute" onclick="execute(document.getElementById('textbox1').value)" type="button" value="Execute" />
```

Answer (score 15):

As opposed to passing the text as a variable, you can use the DOM to retrieve the data in your function:

```
var text = document.getElementsByName("textbox1").value;
```

Comment: It is `getElementsByName` (plural).

Answer (score 3):

You could just get the input value in the onclick-event like so:

```
onclick="execute(document.getElementById('textbox1').value);"
```

You would of course have to add an id to your textbox

Answer (score 3):

This is what I have done. (Adapt from all of your answers)

```
<input name="textbox1" type="text" id="txt1"/>
<input name="buttonExecute" onclick="execute(document.getElementById('txt1').value)" type="button" value="Execute" />
```

It works. Thanks to all of you. :)

Answer (score 2):

if I have understood correct the question :

```html
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<HEAD>
<TITLE>Passing values</TITLE>
<style>
</style>
</HEAD>
Give a number :<input type="number" id="num"><br>
<button onclick="MyFunction(num.value)">Press button...</button>
<script>
function MyFunction(num) {
   document.write("<h1>You gave "+num+"</h1>");
}
</script>
</BODY>
</HTML>
```

Answer (score 1):

document.getElementById('textbox1').value

Comment: The textbox doesn't have an id.

Answer (score 0):

You can get textbox value and Id by the following simple example in dotNet programming

```
<html>
        <head>
         <script type="text/javascript">
             function GetTextboxId_Value(textBox) 
                 {
                 alert(textBox.value);    // To get Text Box Value(Text)
                 alert(textBox.id);      // To get Text Box Id like txtSearch
             }
         </script>     
        </head>
 <body>
 <input id="txtSearch" type="text" onkeyup="GetTextboxId_Value(this)" />  </body>
 </html>
```