# How to pass textbox value to java script on button click event

Tags: javascript, asp.net

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to pass text in a textbox to javascript function?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/765205/how-to-pass-text-in-a-textbox-to-javascript-function)

I need to pass the text box value as parameter of javascript method which will be fired on button click.

```
<asp:TextBox ID="rowID" runat="server"> </asp:TextBox>
        <asp:Button runat="server" ID="Click" OnClientClick="PassValue(Textboxvaluehere)"/>
```

PassValue is JavaScript method.

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: check here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/765205/how-to-pass-text-in-a-textbox-to-javascript-function

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<asp:Button runat="server" ID="Click" OnClientClick="GetTextBoxValue('<%= rowID.ClientID %>'.value)"/>
```

Comment: If i use above code its giving error like Control 'rowID' of type 'TextBox' must be placed inside a form tag with runat=server.

Comment: all asp.net server side controls much be in a `form with runat="server"'. Your textbox isnt?

Comment: No.. now added the form. But while debugging the script the rowID value is undefined. if i remove the .value from '<%= rowID.ClientID %>'.value then the debugging result of parameter is <%= rowID.ClientID %>. its not returning the actual id but retuning the statement

Answer (score 1):

```
<asp:TextBox ID="rowID" runat="server"> </asp:TextBox>
<asp:Button runat="server" ID="Click" OnClientClick="GetTextBoxValue('<%= rowID.ClientID %>')"/>



function GetTextBoxValue(textBoxID){
   var value = window.document.getElementById(textBoxID).value; }
```

Answer (score 1):

Or for cleaner mark-up, bind the event in code-behind at `PageLoad` like this

```
if (!IsPostBack)
{
    string script = String.Format("GetTextBoxValue('{0}')", rowID.ClientID);
    Click.Attributes.Add("onclick", script);
}
```

Now your mark-up can be like this.

```
<asp:TextBox ID="rowID" runat="server"> </asp:TextBox>
<asp:Button ID="Click" runat="server" />
```