# Why do I get this error: "Uncaught ReferenceError: value1 is not defined"?

Tags: javascript, undefined

When I run my code and press either the button 'encode' or the button 'decode' I get this error:
Uncaught ReferenceError: value1 is not defined
at HTMLButtonElement.onclick (HtmlPage2.html:34)

I have tried to move the script as an external file to the area above the `</body>` but I still get the same.

It seems that value1 is not recognized at the input as the 'name'. Shouldn't that get it defined?

Shortly:
I don't understand why value1 is undefined. Could someone please explain?

This is my code :

```js
var newURL;
            function setEncode(myURL) {
                newURL = encodeURIComponent(myURL);
                alert(newURL);
                document.getElementById("info").innerHTML = newURL.toString();
            }
    
            function setDecode(myURL) {
                decodeURL = decodeURIComponent(newURL);
                alert(decodeURL);
                document.getElementById("info").innerHTML = decodeURL.toString();
            }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8" />
        <title></title>
    </head>
    <body>
    
    
    
        <input type="text" name="value1" />
        <button name="encode" onclick="setEncode(value1.value)"> encode </button>
        <button name="decode" onclick="setDecode(value1.value)"> decode </button>
    
        <div id="info"> Decode / encode   </div>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Thank you all!

Comment: consider using a mv* library to do this for you

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to pass text in a textbox to JavaScript function?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/765205/how-to-pass-text-in-a-textbox-to-javascript-function)

Comment: Because you don't declare it anywhere in your code. Giving an HTML element a `name` attribute is not the same thing as declaring a JS variable.

Comment: There's no variable with the name `value1`. I guess you're relying on [named properties](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/#named-access-on-the-window-object), but this only works with `id`s or specific elements (embed, form, img, and object) with a non-empty `name` attribute.

Comment: OK. These make sense. I get it now, thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use id instead of name attribute.

```js
var newURL;
            function setEncode(myURL) {
                newURL = encodeURIComponent(myURL);
                document.getElementById("info").innerHTML = newURL.toString();
            }
    
            function setDecode(myURL) {
                decodeURL = decodeURIComponent(newURL);
                document.getElementById("info").innerHTML = decodeURL.toString();
            }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8" />
        <title></title>
    </head>
    <body>
    
    
    
        <input type="text" id="value1" />
        <button name="encode" onclick="setEncode(value1.value)"> encode </button>
        <button name="decode" onclick="setDecode(value1.value)"> decode </button>
    
        <div id="info"> Decode / encode   </div>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Reason behind this:

If an html element assigned ID attribute, it can be used in javascript with that variable name. For example

```js
myDiv.innerHTML = myDiv.innerHTML + "<p>See? What did I tell you?</p>";
```

```html
<div id="myDiv">
This div ID is myDiv, can be called in JavaScript.
</div>
```

Comment: And why? Just saying "do this..." doesn't help to understand the source of the problem.

Comment: @Andreas Yeah, right. I was trying to explain it in my answer but I saw your comment. And OP seemed to understand what was wrong. I noticed just after I posted my answer.

Comment: My comment is not relevant for your answer (feel free to copy it). An answer should be self-contained and not rely on a comment on the question or another answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can't assign the values directly to the function in your html. But you can can use selectors to get the value from input and attach an event listener to your button However if you you want to do all this on the html you do something like this

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title></title>

    <script>


        // encoding and decoding URIs

        var newURL;
        function setEncode(myURL) {
            newURL = encodeURIComponent(myURL);
            alert(newURL);
            document.getElementById("info").innerHTML = newURL.toString();
        }

        function setDecode() {
            decodeURL = decodeURIComponent(newURL);
            alert(decodeURL);
            document.getElementById("info").innerHTML = decodeURL.toString();
        }




    </script>
</head>
<body>



    <input type="text" id="value1" />
    <button name="encode" onclick="javascript:(function (){let v=document.getElementById('value1');setEncode(v.value)})()"> encode </button>
    <button name="decode" onclick="javascript:(function (){let v=document.getElementById('value1');setEncode(v.value)})()"> decode </button>

    <div id="info"> Decode / encode   </div>
</body>
</html>
```